# SVGKit, how to get all the layers

Tags: ios, svg

Being playing with SVGKit, I more or less find my way around, using code like this:

```
CALayer *layer;
layer=[svgView.document layerWithIdentifier:@"path1730"];
```

But this is when I know the identifier of the layer I want to look at.
Is there a way for me to get a list of all the identifiers (layers) in the document?

Answer (score 1):

You would reference `svgView.document.layerTree`, which is the root of the sublayers. You'll need to recursively descend through the sublayers to catch all of them. Alternately, if you're working from a single `SVGPathView`, you can use its `enumerateChildLayersUsingBlock:` method and pass it a block that will operate on each sublayer in the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I have the feeling it is exactly what I needed.
Now my problem is how to use this information.

Googling on "SVGPathView enumerateChildLayersUsingBlock" doesn't bring more than the access to the GitHub for SVGKit.
I would like to find some sample code using enumerateChildLayersUsingBlock, but it seems there is none available.

The code for enumerateChildLayersUsingBlock itself is simple and straight forward.
But my first question would be: Where do I get the SVGPathView from?

Analyzing the code of SVGKit to figure out how things work would be the hard way.

Comment: It's been awhile since I used SVGKit. I think if you're not already using `SVGPathView`s, you don't need to worry about it. Most people deal with the `SVGDocument` because they're reading and parsing whole SVG files.

Comment: Up to now the way I got the paths from the file was to use sed to extract those by hand from the svg as a text file. It was rather akward but it did the job for a start. Of course this is not the way it should be done, but I don't know the right way. And I didn't find any example either.